# Best Practice for adding jQuery reference in Master Page

Tags: jquery, master-page, custom-masterpage

I have a site collection on the root directory `http://pc51:1001` and a site collection under  the sites  directory `http://pc51:1001/sites/First` .

I am trying to add jQuery file reference in Master Page so it will work on both site collections

What is the best practice method for adding a jQuery reference in the Master Page?

My jQuery file resides in `/Style Library/ABC/Js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js`

Comment: If this isn't a duplicate of http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86979/adding-jquery-to-master-page?rq=1 then it's a duplicate of http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151177/adding-jquery-and-bootstrap-references-to-master-page?rq=1 (and tons of other similar questions)... and the accepted answer will break MDS for 2013/O365 users, so is actively harmful

Comment: i have found those question that u had mention , And I have checked his answer,it does not work  .so i had post this question.   the answer given by Hardik worked for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below line in your master page to access your JS file anywhere from entire site collection.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<asp:Literal runat='server' Text='<%$SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/Envera/Js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js%>' />"></script>
```

Comment: I was looking for the same. It worked for me. 
Found this post at the right time.
Cheers!

Comment: it worked for me...

Comment: This will break MDS for 2013/O365 users